# angular/karma/jasmine global variable

Tags: angularjs, global-variables, jasmine, karma-runner

I have global object in html file with some information from backend

```
    <script>
        APP = {
            BASE_URL: '{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost }}{{ app.request.baseUrl }}',
            SESSION_LIFETIME: '{{ app.session.metadataBag.lifetime }}',
            SESSION_EXPIRATION: '{{ app.session.metadataBag.created + app.session.metadataBag.lifetime }}'
        };
    </script>
```

Then i get information from APP in factory like

```
var url = APP.BASE_URL + '/projects';
```

but when I run karma I get an error" APP in Factory is undefined.

Also when I add APP as constant it doesnt work too

```
angular.module('invoiceApp', [])
.constant('config', {
    BASE_URL: 'my test url in angular'
})
.run(function($rootScope, config) {
    console.log(APP)
    console.log(config)
```

In Karma console:
config.log(APP) is undefined 
config.log(config) is Object {BASE_URL: 'my test url in angular'}

So how to get the right way to object outside the angular in Angular/Karma/Jasmine ?

Comment: are you using angular mocks to make "invoiceApp" module available?

Comment: My mistake, if I understand the question, your problem is the fact that you have javascript which is declared inline in the HTML document. and the problem is its not available to karma, because the karma.conf is not aware of the inline script

Comment: Ok, so is there any solution for this?